# How to make graphic overlay elements responsiveness in live preview Camera?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-mlkit

Currently I'm developing a project that implements Object detection / tracking but now I need to add a new functionality that when user want to chose an element that is detected using Live Camera Preview may be possible to select it touching the reticle element in the center of their bounding box.

This is how it currently [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkCeM.png) my app.

Nowadays I am able to draw a customized bounding box and a customized reticle that fit in the center of the bounding box, Im also able to show many bounding box as needed with mutliple object detection. So far that's what I can do. I see that on presentation on 2019 of the ML Kit [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEsncYGeMF8) they use another method using live preview camera, their pipeline consist on hold camera a couple of seconds to make a search. I want to do a similar thing but instead of hold camera an wait a couple of seconds, I want to give the chance to the app user to chose the element.
I use
[ML Kit Vision Quickstart Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart) and [ML Kit Showcase App with Material Design](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/mlkit-material-android) as base of my project, I was able to implement succesfully different stuff of both projects.
I currently use kotlin but I can also work with Java code, so no problem. Also, if anyone thinks it's necessary, I can add code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're also using a single custom view to draw all these bounding boxes and reticles like MLKit Samples do (e.g. [GraphicOverlay](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/material-showcase/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/md/camera/GraphicOverlay.kt) in the MLKit Showcase App), then you can override its [#onToucheEvent](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views#custom-click-events) method to simulate a click event on reticle element (touching point is inside the reticle area) and do whatever what you want after it's triggered.

Comment: Yes! Thats my case, I have a custom view for both to draw the bounidng box and the reticle... Do you know some example/resources to work with painted objects in Views?

Comment: Sorry I don't, but like I mentioned before, you may just need to track the location of painted objects in your custom view and then override its #onTouchEvent to detect the click event on the painted object.